# Как определить дату и время пользователя в php?

Tags: php, дата

Как определить дату и время у пользователя? Если зайдет он на сайт, находясь в Москве, то вывести время в Москве, если в Нью-Йорке - нью-йоркское.
Пытался определять с помощью `getdate()`, `localtime()`, `date('h-i-s')`
Выводит везде одно и то же время - берлинское.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Пытался определять с помощью getdate(), localtime(), date('h-i-s')
>   Выводит везде одно и то же время - берлинское.

Так как php работает на сервере, то и функции возвращают серверное время.

Чтобы получить время пользователя, надо на его компьютере запустить код определения времени. Для этого подходит javascript и его функции работы с датой https://learn.javascript.ru/datetime

Дальше: если нужно ли время юзера знать на сервере, тогда придется отправлять полученное время или часовой пояс на сервер посредством ajax например, если время на сервере не нужно, а требуется пересчитать все метки времени на отображаемой странице, то следует с сервера в этой странице передавать его часовой пояс, чтобы js вычислял разницу с часовым поясом пользователя и производил пересчет.

P.S. Совсем хитрый вариант: по ip юзера получать его местонахождение, узнавать часовой пояс и прямо на сервере пересчитывать время.

Comment: ps-вариант интересный, спасибо, забыл про ajax, вообще изи:D